# I am having trouble installing Zurb Foundation for HTML Emails

Tags: node.js, installation, gulp, zurb-foundation

I  was able to download Foundation, but when I try to run the foundation new --framework emails command, it doesn't work and gives me this error message.

What should I do?

> Message:

```
fs.js:27
const { Math, Object, Reflect } = primordials;

ReferenceError: primordials is not defined

at fs.js:27:35

at req_ (/Users/evanscott/.fnm/node-versions/v12.0.0/installation/lib/node_modules/foundation-cli/node_modules/natives/index.js:143:24)

at Object.req [as require] (/Users/evanscott/.fnm/node-versions/v12.0.0/installation/lib/node_modules/foundation-cli/node_modules/natives/index.js:55:10)

at Object. (/Users/evanscott/.fnm/node-versions/v12.0.0/installation/lib/node_modules/foundation-cli/node_modules/graceful-fs/fs.js:1:37)

at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:759:30)

at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:770:10)

at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:628:32)

at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:555:12)

at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:666:19)

at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16:16)
```

I tried sudo npm install primordial after and this is what I got,

```
npm WARN deprecated circular-json@0.3.3: CircularJSON is in maintenance only, flatted is its successor.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@1.2.7: core-js@<2.6.5 is no longer maintained. Please, upgrade to core-js@3 or at least to actual version of core-js@2.

> primordial@0.11.0 preinstall /Users/evanscott/node_modules/primordial
> npm install n --global && n lts

npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /Users/evanscott/.fnm/node-versions/v12.0.0/installation/lib/node_modules/n
npm ERR! path /Users/evanscott/.fnm/node-versions/v12.0.0/installation/lib/node_modules/n
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/Users/evanscott/.fnm/node-versions/v12.0.0/installation/lib/node_modules/n'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/Users/evanscott/.fnm/node-versions/v12.0.0/installation/lib/node_modules/n'] {
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access ' +
npm ERR!     "'/Users/evanscott/.fnm/node-versions/v12.0.0/installation/lib/node_modules/n'",
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/Users/evanscott/.fnm/node-versions/v12.0.0/installation/lib/node_modules/n'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/evanscott/.npm/_logs/2019-05-05T07_18_27_777Z-debug.log
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/evanscott/package.json'
npm WARN evanscott No description
npm WARN evanscott No repository field.
npm WARN evanscott No README data
npm WARN evanscott No license field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 243
npm ERR! primordial@0.11.0 preinstall: `npm install n --global && n lts`
npm ERR! Exit status 243
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the primordial@0.11.0 preinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/evanscott/.npm/_logs/2019-05-05T07_18_33_460Z-debug.log
```

I then tried to switch to my projects folder and do the foundations command and it didn't work.

Any other ideas?

I think the problem has to do with Gulp and the global cli, which they may have discontinued? I'm not sure. I think that the version of Gulp is not compatible with Node. I upgraded both, and it doesn't work. It briefly worked when I installed Ubuntu which was running a lower version of node but I had to upgrade that and then it stopped working.

I  was able to download Foundation, but when I try to run the foundation new --framework emails command, it doesn't work and gives me this error message.

I tried sudo npm install primordial after and this is what I got `(error message 2)`

I then tried to switch to my projects folder and do the foundations command and it didn't work.

Any other ideas?

Error messages are above

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56245622/foundation-referenceerror-primordials-is-not-define-when-starting-a-foundati Please switch to NodeJS 10. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/56253873/753676

Comment: "sudo npm install primordial" Please never run any npm command with sudo, this will break your setup and produce many more eaccess errors. Also primordial is an internal module of NodeJS, not a package.